# Use grub rescue to boot from Windows XP partition, CD or USB

Tags: grub2

I just attempted to reinstall Lubuntu using [my own guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76286/33094). However, my LiveCD was (appearantly) damaged, which caused installation to fail. Now, when I restart the PC, I get dropped into a `grub rescue>` prompt.

Now how can I use that prompt to:

1. Boot to the Windows XP partition that is on the hard drive
   or
2. Boot from a (new) LiveCD/LiveUSB to fix everything.

The boot order is set to prefer the HDD, and I can't change it due to a password I don't know.

Comment: @don_crissti `grub rescue`.

Comment: @don_crissti 'just'? I have to screw it open in that case D: I hope there's another solution...

Comment: Might've missed the rescue bit in my answer. Why not just boot the livecd you have? Even if it is damaged, in order to start the installation in the first place, it must've booted in a usable system which should be suitable for making repairs or creating a new USB image.

Comment: @frostschutz I can't use the LiveCD thanks to the boot order + bios password

Comment: reset your bios password then, that's something you'd have to do sooner or later anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it by going to another computer with Windows XP, plugging in a flash drive, installing  Lubuntu on it (NOT a LiveUSB, a real install), then plugging it in the computer with the broken grub, turning it on, and typing:

```
set prefix=(hd1,1)/grub
set root=(hd1,1)
insmod normal
normal
```

Then the grub menu of the Lubuntu on the USB drive showed up, chose the Windows XP entry (That was created because I created the USB from a Windows XP PC), and then I could [reinstall Lubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76286/33094). Now everything is working fine again.

Answer (score -1):

for Windows XP:

```
    search --file --no-floppy --set=root /ntldr
    ntldr /ntldr
    boot
```

for Windows 7:

```
    search --file --no-floppy --set=root /bootmgr
    ntldr /bootmgr
    boot
```

CD/USB depends, however on most machines, a Grub loaded from HDD cannot see USB/CD drives, so it's not possible. The machine has to boot from those drives directly.